# How to check how many constants are in enumeration?

Tags: java, enumeration

I have a enum:

```
public enum Platform {
  Xbox360, XboxOne, Playstation3,
  Playstation4, PC 
}
```

I want to iterate and print all constants from it. How can I get size ?
Or for this purpose I shouldn't use enumeration but let say arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply get a array of the enum constants using `<EnumName>.values()`

```
Platform[] platforms = Platform.values();
```

You can use that array to get the number of elements/iterate through the elements.

Comment: So my thoughts with array were right. Only I didn't know what tools to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
int size = Platform.values().length;
```

Or iterate them:

```
for (Platform platform : Platform.values()) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate you can do the following:

```
for(Platform platform : Platform.values()){
  //your code
}
```